# Compile an old project using autotools

Tags: c++, gcc, centos, autotools, chord

I have been struggling with this error when I try to run the configure script. It is a 12 years old library. First I tried to generate the configure script by using modern version of all the autotools and GCC.

Then, I tried to generate it by using tools versions of that time but when I run the configure file I still get the same errors which is always the broken variable **CPPFLAGS**

Here is the configure error:

```
checking for GMP library... checking for gmp.h... 
configure: error: Could not find gmp.h header
```

Here is the config.log section which describe the error:

```
 configure:22748: gcc34 -c -g -O2  -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite/$(srcdir); export srcdir;     \                                                                      
 /home/vicente/sfslite/async -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite/$(srcdir); export srcdir;      \                                                                                                                  
 /home/vicente/sfslite/arpc -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite/$(srcdir); export srcdir;     \                                                                                                                    
 /home/vicente/sfslite/crypt -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite/$(srcdir); export srcdir;      \                                                                                                                  
 /home/vicente/sfslite/sfsmisc -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite/$(srcdir); export srcdir;      \                                                                                                                
 /home/vicente/sfslite/libsfs -I/home/vicente/build/chord/../sfslite/svc -I/usr/include conftest.c >&5                                                                                                                
 gcc34: export: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                             
 gcc34: srcdir;: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                            
 gcc34: \: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                  
 gcc34: export: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                             
 gcc34: srcdir;: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                            
 gcc34: \: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                  
 gcc34: export: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                             
 gcc34: srcdir;: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                            
 gcc34: \: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                  
 gcc34: export: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                             
 gcc34: srcdir;: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                            
 gcc34: \: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                  
 gcc34: export: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                             
 gcc34: srcdir;: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                            
 gcc34: \: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                  
 configure:22754: $? = 1                                                                                                                                                                                              
 configure: failed program was:
```

I wonder if there is someone who went through a similar problem.
Thanks!

Version of tools:

- GCC 3.4, 4.4, 4.7.2
- Autoconf/aclocal/autoheader 2.59, 2.69
- Automake 1.9.6, 1.15
- OS: Centos 5.9, Ubuntu 12.04 all of them 64bits

Link of the program:
https://github.com/sit/dht

### EDITED:

Here is the section of the configure script around the line 22754:

```
 cat confdefs.h >>conftest.$ac_ext
 cat >>conftest.$ac_ext <<_ACEOF
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
 #include "gmp.h"
 int
 main ()
 {
 0
   ;
   return 0;
 }
 _ACEOF
 rm -f conftest.$ac_objext
 if { (eval echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \"$ac_compile\"") >&5
   (eval $ac_compile) 2>conftest.er1
   ac_status=$?
   grep -v '^ *+' conftest.er1 >conftest.err
   rm -f conftest.er1
   cat conftest.err >&5
   echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5  # line 22754
   (exit $ac_status); } &&
     { ac_try='test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag"
             || test ! -s conftest.err'
   { (eval echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \"$ac_try\"") >&5
   (eval $ac_try) 2>&5
   ac_status=$?
   echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
   (exit $ac_status); }; } &&
     { ac_try='test -s conftest.$ac_objext'
   { (eval echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \"$ac_try\"") >&5
   (eval $ac_try) 2>&5
   ac_status=$?
   echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
   (exit $ac_status); }; }; then
   sfs_cv_gmp_h="${iflags}"; break
 else
   echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
 sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

 fi
```

Comment: in this case it might also be useful to show the lines from the generated configure script around the error (line 22748). Also you might try autoconf 2.13 (which was popular the most popular autoconf version in the past).

Comment: Check the edit. I haven't tried the autoconf 2.13 yet, ill give a try :)